# How to reverse bars on log scale in geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(periodo = c("2T", "2T", "3T", "3T", "1T", "1T", 
"3T", "3T", "4T", "4T", "1T", "1T", "2T", "2T", "3T", "3T", "4T", 
"4T", "1T", "1T", "2T", "2T", "3T", "3T", "4T", "4T", "1T", "1T", 
"2T", "2T", "3T", "3T", "4T", "4T", "1T", "1T", "1S", "2S", "1S", 
"2S", "1S", "2S", "2S", "2S", "1S", "1S"), valor = c(0.005248075, 
0.005128614, 0.0027195, 0.0151865, 0.002138615, 0.0154045, 0.00258683684210526, 
0.010892, 0.02037825, 0.0232392666666667, 0.026491725, 0.0232410291666667, 
0.026384125, 0.0232420416666667, 0.00438416666666667, 0.00122625, 
0.0125198083333333, 0.00935866250000001, 0.00981484583333334, 
0.0072391375, 0.0214400530654592, 0.0214486897415176, 0.0597089068767695, 
0.0116124859053284, 0.00311100760334978, 0.00369158618252611, 
0.02056125, 0.00690491666666667, 0.00277258333333333, 0.00211695833333333, 
0.00235166666666667, 0.00235791666666667, 0.0176666666666667, 
0.025125, 0.0236666666666667, 0.0212916666666667, 0.000170841666666667, 
0.000172070833333333, 0.0005342625, 0.00141873333333333, 0.00107964166666667, 
0.00191949166666667, 0.000509783333333334, 0.0013974, 0.002087, 
0.000502616666666667), nombre = structure(c(4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("P-2", "R-5", 
"E-3", "R-4"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
```

chart

```
data %>%
ggplot(aes(periodo, valor, fill = nombre)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.3, preserve = "single")) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    label_y,
    trans = "log10",
    limits = 10^c(-5, 0),
    breaks = 10^c(-5:0)
  )
```

Be default the bars are upside down, which is confusing because I read the column `valor` from bottom to top.
[image]

Expected output: I need the bars to be upside down like "normal".

[image]

Comment: the fundamental problem here is that *log scales are not recommended for bar plots* (web-search will probably tell you why; basically, it violates the reader expectation that bar plots will be anchored at zero). You can probably define a custom transformation ...

Comment: I understand. So I would need to plot the bars from 1er-05 to `y`. Any idea on how to start this idea?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack where we shift the plotted values to be >1, then shift the labels the same amount:

(Btw I would second the comment that bar charts will be unavoidably misleading on a log scale, since we are taught to interpret length as proportional to value. `geom_point` might be a simpler choice here, avoiding the need for any adjustments.)

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(periodo, valor*1e5, fill = nombre)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.3, preserve = "single")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "valor",
    trans = "log10",
    limits = 10^c(0, 5),
    breaks = 10^c(0:5),
    labels = scales::scientific(10^c(-5:0))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: the alternative way I was thinking of doing this was a custom scale that inverted the sign of the logs but used the original sign in the labels ...