# How to reverse bars in geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I wanted to plot the results of a run in a similar fashion as Strava does. I used geom_col to plot the data but I want to have the bars from the bottom instead of from the top whilst remaining the reversed y-axis (because a higher value for pace is a lower speed).

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(km = 1:20, avePace = c(321, 301, 319, 312, 312, 313, 305, 309, 313, 341,
                                       352, 352, 355, 355, 372, 362, 372, 363, 340, 316))


ggplot(data = df, aes(x=km, y = avePace, fill = avePace)) +
 geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, orientation="x") +
 scale_fill_distiller() +
 scale_y_reverse(labels = function(t) strftime(t, "%M:%S")) +
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(7*60, 3*60 )) +
 ylab("Pace (min/km)")
```

I realize this is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478593/how-to-reverse-bars-on-log-scale-in-geom-col) as asked by Alvaro Morales, but I cannot reproduce the suggested solution.

[image]

The desired image looks something like this: [image: Strava example]

Comment: From what number should the bars start? Aside from that, I'll just leave the unsolicited advice that maybe a bar chart isn't the ideal visualisation for this kind of data as the length of the bar doesn't represent anything.

Comment: @teunbrand Exactly. Switch to a line plot and the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close to what you need with a `reciprocal` transformation, from the `scales` package:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=km, y = avePace, fill = avePace)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE, orientation="x") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = "reciprocal"
    labels = function(t) strftime(as.POSIXlt(t, origin = as.Date("1970-01-01")), "%M:%S"))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(7*60, 3*60 )) +
  ylab("Pace (min/km)")
```

[image]

But, as @teunbrand noted on his comment, this is the wrong visualization for this type of data.  The origin of the bars is meaningless (infinite speed?) and so their size is not comparable. E.g.: the bar for km 15 (372 s/km) is about half the size of the bar for km 1 (321 s/km).  But you weren't going at half as fast: on km 1 you were doing 3.12 m/s and on km 15 you were doing 2.69 m/s.

Comment: Thanks! This did solve my problem. Had to upgrade to 43.3. (from 4.3.2) to get the labels to show on the y-axis but it works like a charm. I do by the way agree with the statements that a bar graph may not be a good representation but is does give an impression of the relative speed between kilometers and over time. And not more than an impression.

Answer (score 2):

This solution focuses the y-axis to the nearest minutes. But this is really just an obfuscation of the bar-origin issue previously mentioned.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  km = 1:20, 
  avePace = c(
    321, 301, 319, 312, 312, 313, 305, 309, 313, 341, 
    352, 352, 355, 355, 372, 362, 372, 363, 340, 316
  )
)

min_min <- floor(min(df$avePace) / 60) * 60
max_min <- ceiling(max(df$avePace) / 60) * 60

df$bar_heights <- max_min - df$avePace

b <- seq(0, max_min - min_min, 60)
l <- strftime(rev(b) + min_min, "%M:%S/km")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=km, y = bar_heights, fill = avePace)) +
 geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = b, labels = l) + 
 scale_fill_distiller() + 
ylab("Pace (min/km)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>